# Keeping fourth finger up when playing thirds

Tags: piano, blues

Help please. When playing thirds (blues riff), using the third and fifth fingers, the fourth one sometimes goes down as well, particularly when I speed up. Are there any exercises I can use to correct this deficiency?

Comment: Would it be possible to post a photo of how your hand looks when the problem occurs?

Comment: I think this is called "independence of fingers" in general.  Google seems to have a lot of suggestions for that.  Also, do you practice scales in thirds when you're doing your scales?  I think this is one of those things that improve with five minutes a day.  I think what happens is that your brain-finger system will get the hang of the brain sending one signal to two fingers at once, like when a gate opens and shuts.  I think the key is to raise two fingers as you are bringing two fingers down, with the raising being the thing to focus on primarily -- but piano is not my primary instrument!

Comment: Also maybe make sure you've got a good fingering I guess.

Comment: Does your fourth finger go down so hard that it accidentally plays notes?

Comment: How about Hanon?  (but this is a months possibly years long solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fourth and fifth finger are physically linked (which is one of the limitations of piano playing). Thus it is not possible to move your pinky quickly while keeping the ring finger completely still. But you can try to get as much control over it as possible. One exercise for this would be:

Put all five fingers on the keys (or on some surface, but keys give resistance) and lifting and putting down again the ring finger a few times and then alternate between middle finger, ring finger and pinky. Try not to move the rest of your fingers without putting strain on them. When you get comfortable with this you can then try to do the same in thirds with index+ring finger and middle finger+pinky.

Comment: How do I accept this answer?

Comment: @jethroburns To accept an answer, click on the check-mark to the left of the text.